# Android SQLlite database join using foreign key getting error

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("CREATE TABLE " + LecturesTable.TABLE_NAME + " (");
    sb.append(BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ");
    sb.append(LecturesColumns.TITLE + " TEXT, ");
    sb.append(LecturesColumns.SPEAKER_ID + " INTEGER, ");
    sb.append(LecturesColumns.START_TIME + " DATETIME, ");
    sb.append(LecturesColumns.END_TIME + " DATETIME, ");
    sb.append(LecturesColumns.TYPE + " TEXT, ");
    sb.append(LecturesColumns.PLACE_ID + " INTEGER, ");
    sb.append(LecturesColumns.DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, ");
    sb.append("FOREIGN KEY(" + LecturesColumns.SPEAKER_ID + ") "
            + "REFERENCES " + SpeakersTable.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + BaseColumns._ID + "), ");
    sb.append("FOREIGN KEY(" + LecturesColumns.PLACE_ID + ") "
            + "REFERENCES " + PlacesTable.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + BaseColumns._ID + ")");
    sb.append(");");
    db.execSQL(sb.toString());
}

public long insert(String[] data) {
        insertStatement.clearBindings();
        insertStatement.bindLong(1, Long.valueOf(data[0]));
        insertStatement.bindString(2, data[1]);
        insertStatement.bindLong(3, Long.valueOf(data[2]));
        insertStatement.bindString(4, data[3]);
        insertStatement.bindString(5, data[4]);
        insertStatement.bindString(6, data[5]);
        insertStatement.bindLong(7, Long.valueOf(data[6]));
        insertStatement.bindString(8, data[7]);
        return insertStatement.executeInsert();
    }
```

> error android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)

Comment: Show some example data, and the actual SQL statement that fails.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable foreign key support first

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
```

#### EDIT

Are you sure you have the rows with the right values in SpeakersTable and PlacesTable?

You can add a constraint name to receive a more accurate error message if fails

```
"CONSTRAINT speakers FOREIGN KEY(" ...
```

Comment: stll does'nt working, this is my openhelper method public void onOpen(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
  super.onOpen(db);
  if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
   db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA foreign_keys", null);
   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int result = c.getInt(0);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "SQLite foreign key support (1 is on, 0 is off): " + result);
   } else {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "SQLite foreign key support NOT AVAILABLE");
   }
   if (!c.isClosed()) {
    c.close();
   }
  }
 }

Answer (score -1):

Error code 19 means you just break a table constraint like "NOT NULL", "UNIQUE", etc in your insert method

Please look at [SQLiteErrorCode](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)